# Encoding of requirement file using pip

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, locale

On OSX (El Capitan, 10.11.6), using virtualenv (15.1.0), I am getting an error when installing requirements from a text file with pip (9.0.1):

```
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

but not when looping over each requirement manually:

```
for r in $(cat requirements.txt); do pip install "$r"; done
```

This makes me think there might be an issue with the default encoding assumed by pip when reading the requirements file. **Is there a way (environment variable, I presume) to set the default encoding of requirement files?**

---

The error I get is:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/path/to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 312, in run
    wheel_cache
  File "/path/to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 295, in populate_requirement_set
    wheel_cache=wheel_cache):
  File "/path/to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 84, in parse_requirements
    filename, comes_from=comes_from, session=session
  File "/path/to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 422, in get_file_content
    content = auto_decode(f.read())
  File "/path/to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/encoding.py", line 31, in auto_decode
    return data.decode(locale.getpreferredencoding(False))
LookupError: unknown encoding:
```

---

The following test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import locale

print sys.stdin.encoding
print locale.getpreferredencoding()
print locale.getpreferredencoding(False)
print sys.getdefaultencoding()
print sys.getfilesystemencoding()
```

returns:

```
None

US-ASCII
ascii
utf-8
```

---

From the command-line:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="utf-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: I was hit by the same bug and I am not sure what is causing it but clearly it happens only with python2.7 on MacOS. My list of locales is very different but this should not matter because it did not change.

Answer (score 0):

According to your test the `locale.getpreferredencoding()` is absent — it should look like this:

```
UTF-8
UTF-8
US-ASCII
ascii
utf-8
```

Doing `locale` mine looks *almost* like yours (other than US vs GB and `LC_CTYPE`). It does seem peculiar that `LC_CTYPE` seems different, and maybe worth looking into as to why.

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

There are a couple of things you can try to correct the issue, the first being your shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Try changing it to this perhaps, as `#!/usr/bin/env python` might not set the locale properly. If that doesn't work you can always try forcing the encoding within your script:

```
import locale

loc = locale.getlocale()

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')   # use user's preferred locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'C')  # use default (C) locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, loc)  # restore saved locale

# OR

locale.getpreferredencoding(do_setlocale=True) or "utf-8"

# OR

if locale.getpreferredencoding() == '':
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'UTF-8')
```

Ultimately you'll want to figure out why `locale.getpreferredencoding()` is coming up empty for the first couple tests, and why you have a mismatched `LC_CTYPE` set in your locale.

Comment: This might be going in the right direction, but that's not a solution. The `#!/usr/bin/env python` is definitely the one that should be used (otherwise it calls the system's python, not the one setup by virtualenv), and I cannot force the locale manually because there is no user script involved (the problem occurs within pip). I am not even sure that the preferred encoding being empty is the issue here, since the error traces back to `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`, which is not empty.

Comment: @Sheljohn: Yeah I missed the `False` value, thinking it was empty; I guess the next thing would be to determine why the first two items come back blank, and as to why `LC_CTYPE` doesn't match up with your other locale values (notice it's not `en_GB.UTF-8`)...