# VScode pylint on OSX fails silently

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

I've exhausted the list of things to check, the Python extension doesn't seem to be working on my OSX laptop.

I reinstalled the Python extension, checked that all my settings were set as in the [documentation with `pylint`](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Linting#pylint), and defined the relevant settings in my user configuration:

```
// Python settings
"python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
"python.formatting.formatOnSave": false,
"python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
"python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/local/bin/pylint",
"python.linting.pylintArgs": []
```

*(Full configuration [here](http://pastebin.com/aZt1WuWc))*

But no luck, no error message, no warning, nothing. The following file doesn't show me any error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def foo
    pass
```

Maybe there is something I am missing in my [configuration](http://pastebin.com/aZt1WuWc)? The extension works brilliantly in Linux, so I must be doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the `jedi` library with pip, adding the path in my user settings, and reloading the window, I then got an error with pylint:

```
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/reporters/__init__.py", line 72, in encode
    locale.getdefaultlocale()[1] or
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: utf-8
```

This is a problem I have had [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41620257/472610), and I thought I had fixed by adding the following lines to my `.bash_profile`:

```
# UTF-8 terminal
export LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

But actually I only had `export LC_CTYPE="utf-8"`. Adding the previous lines to my `.bash_profile` instead, and restarting VScode solved the problem for me.